# How to print a message in one single line in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, line, printk

I am making a simple enque/deque program in kernel. I want to print message in kernel, and this is what I got:

```
[18594.595747] Enqueue 3 
[18594.595748]  queue :  
[18594.595751] 2 
[18594.595751] 1 
[18594.595752] 3
```

But I want to print this without newline:

```
[8594.595747] Enqueue 3 
[18594.595748]  queue : 2 1 3
```

This is a part of my code:

```
   printk(KERN_ALERT "Enqueue %d \n queue :  ", a);
   rear++;
   for(i = front; i<rear; i++)
      printk(KERN_ALERT "%d ", queue_test[i]);
```

In short, I want to print in kernel a message in one line. But if I use printk, it changes line automatically. How do I print a message in one line?

Comment: I guess you need `printk(KERN_CONT …);` or `pr_cont(…);` depends on your needs. But usually it's a bad idea, means you have to rethink what you are trying to do and do this in another way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To prevent a new line from being started, use `KERN_CONT`:

```c
printk(KERN_ALERT "self destruction commences in ");
printk(KERN_CONT "%d", time_remaining);
printk(KERN_CONT " minutes\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Debugging by printing](http://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing)

```
printk(KERN_ERR "Doing something was ");
/* <100 lines of whatever>*/
if (success)
   printk(KERN_CONT "successful\n");
else
   printk(KERN_CONT "NOT successful\n");
```

Logging prints should be safe: SFP vs single CPU.